# Step response with bodegraph package

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, bodegraph

I discovered `bodegraph` package lately and I found out that it allows drawing step responses on the [package documentation](http://ctan.epst-tlemcen.dz/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/bodegraph/bodegraph.pdf). So  I copy-pasted the code on page 19 as a first try but the desired graph doesn't show.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{bodegraph}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=5/2,yscale=7/2]
\RepTemp*[color=black,samples=31,smooth,
]{0:1.8}{
-.198*exp(-35.4*x)-.638*exp(-2.28*x)*cos(18.3*x)
-.462*exp(-2.28*x)*sin(18.3*x)+.833
}{[right]{\small 1}}
\RepTemp*[color=blue,samples=31,smooth
,]{0:1.8}{
1-.117*exp(-24.1*x)-.883*exp(-2.94*x)*cos(7.03*x)
-.769*exp(-2.94*x)*sin(7.03*x)
}{[right]{\small 2}}
\def\valmaxx{1.8}
\def\valmaxy{1.2}
\TempGrid[xstep=0.2,ystep=0.2]
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

The actual output :
[image]

I know that I can create the same graph using `pgfplot` , but I'd like to use `bodegraph` only.

Comment: When compiling with `pdfLateX` with the latest version of `MikTeX`, I get the same result as on page 19 of the documentation. Which compilation engine do you use? Is your LaTeX distribution up to date?

Comment: I'm using `TexMaker` 5.0.3, So I've to upgrade to version 5.0.4 .?  I just tried `pdfLatex` with `MikTex` and I''m encountering the same problem.

Comment: The last MikTeX version is `(MiKTeX 20.6.29)`. You can find it by compiling any document and looking at the first line of the `.log` file.

Comment: I just checked it and it is up to date

Comment: Which compilation engine do you use? pdfLaTeX? LaTeX ? LuaLaTeX ? Another one?

Comment: I use pdfLatex.

Comment: Me too, what is your operating system? Windows? Mac? Linux?

Comment: My operating system is Windows 10

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111307/discussion-between-andrec-and-hibou).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is due to the `gnuplot` software, just installing it won't be  enough, it needs to be on Windows `PATH`. It can be done by checking the box **Add gnuplot to PATH** during the install procedure or add it manually like shown [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) [image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the installation window showing where to click during installation

Comment: +1 It's perfect!